# How to extract string within parentheses that doesn't start with specific keywords (with negative look behind assertion?)

Tags: python, regex, negative-lookbehind

I would like to find the string position of the (test) string from the string below (the one that neither start with for or or):

```
 •  <test>* (for test) (or test) (test)
```

Is it possible to find the specific string using negative look behind assertion? I was using this regex but i am missing something:

```
m_comments = re.search('(?<!\(for)|(?<!\(or)', line)
```

also can we combine an or statement in a look behind assertion?

Note: test can be any possible string:

```
<an other eg> (for another test) (or with this) (anything)
```

Comment: I don't know how to use regex but shouldn't it be easy to search for a space between parantheses and if there is no space between them u can assume this parantheses to be the right one?

Comment: I want to catch only (test) not all string within parantheses

Comment: You don't need lookbehind: `(\([^fo]\|f[^o]\|fo[^r]\|for[^ ]\|o[^r]\|or[^ ]).*)`

:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
\((?!for|or).*?\)
```

see it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?321j2)

With the `\(.*?\)` I am matching everything from an opening bracket to the first closing bracket.

Then I use a negative lookahead `(?!for|or)` to ensure that there is no "for" and no "or" directly after the opening bracket.

In a lookbehind assertion in Python it is not possible to use alternations. They have to be of fixed length.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the `find` string method, rather than regex:

```
string_to_look_up.find('(test)')
```

Comment: @tiguero Then what's to stop you writing `def blah(string, what): return string.find('({})'.format(what))` ?

Comment: @JonClements what will this do exactly?

Comment: @tiguero errr... creates a function that finds `what` surrounded by `(` and `)` in `string`? `pos = blah(line, 'test'); pos = blah(line, 'monkey')` etc...